# Ionic 4 - hide android navigation bar (bottom)

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, android-navigation-bar

When ion-input has focus it shows the navigation bar. When the focus is changed navigation bar hides.
here is the code.

**Used in app.component.ts**

```
this.androidFullScreen.isImmersiveModeSupported().then(() => this.androidFullScreen.immersiveMode());
```

On the signUp page, I have 2 input fields. When the 1st field is clicked the ion input has focus and the navigation bar at the bottom is shown.

Already tried (ionFocus)= "hideNavigationBar()"

```
hideNavigationBar() {
   this.androidFullScreen.setSystemUiVisibility(AndroidSystemUiFlags.LayoutStable | 
   AndroidSystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation | AndroidSystemUiFlags.HideNavigation);
}
```

Also, tried to hide the navigation bar when the soft keyboard is shown.

```
this.keyboard.onKeyboardWillShow().subscribe(()=> { 
this.keyboard.hide();
this.androidFullScreen.setSystemUiVisibility(
          AndroidSystemUiFlags.HideNavigation |
          AndroidSystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation |
          AndroidSystemUiFlags.Immersive |
          AndroidSystemUiFlags.LayoutStable);
});
```

But still, the navigation bar is shown.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

That you can achieve using cordova plugin.

Install

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-navigationbar
npm install @ionic-native/navigation-bar
```

Code Side

```
import { NavigationBar } from '@ionic-native/navigation-bar/ngx';

constructor(private navigationBar: NavigationBar) { }

...

let autoHide: boolean = true;
this.navigationBar.setUp(autoHide);
```

Detailed Description is here. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/navigation-bar

Comment: Tried the above as well.
this.navigationBar.setUp(autoHide);
It doesn't work.

Comment: My case is when we have a focus on the ion-input field the navigation bar should hide as I have disabled the keyboard.

Tried this :
<ion-input (ionFocus)= "hideNavigationBar()" />
hideNavigationBar() { 
 this.navigationBar.setUp(true);
 this.navigationBar.hideNavigationBar();
  // Tried both of them. (2nd works but not when focus is on input field)
}

Comment: if its one line you can directly write into ionFocus. You use case is bit difficult it seems.

Comment: You need to try to achieve based on your use case. Also you should implement ionFocus as well as ionBlur to show navigation bar again.

Comment: In my case, the navigation bar  and soft keyboard is not needed at all

I tried with (ionFocus) and (ionBlur) , it doesn't work.

It only works when softkeyboard is shown and then on keyboard.onKeyboardWillShow() { // hide navigation bar } but this is not my case.